# Mobile Safari, window.innerHeight without address bar

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

On mobile safari, you can use the `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` technique to hide the address bar.  Once the address bar is hidden, I expected `window.innerHeight` to be increased by ~60px.  But it doesn't.

How can I determine the usable screen space, after the address bar is hidden?

---

### Update:

A little code:

```
$(window).load ()->
  alert window.innerHeight
  window.scrollTo(0, 0) #hide the address bar
  delayedHeightCheck = ()->
    alert window.innerHeight
  setTimeout(delayedHeightCheck, 0) #wait until next event loop to check height after address bar hide
```

That code alerts `444` on the first `alert()` and `504` on the second alert.  So it seems like mobile safari is doing the right thing.

I was confused, because I'm using this as part of a jQuery widget, where `delayedHeightCheck` becomes `$(document).myWidget()`.  I had a height option that I was setting as `window.innerHeight`.  If I replace that option with a function (`()-> (window.innerHeight)`) instead, I get the expected results.